Absoluteness of ordinal multiplication (as defined in Kunen).
In Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs", p. 128, theorem 5.5 in chapter IV, he wants to prove the following:

For ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the following statement is absolute for any transitive model satisfying $\sf{ZF}-\sf{P}$: $$\alpha \cdot \beta$$

He gives the following proof:

$$\alpha \cdot \beta = \mathrm{type}(\beta \times \alpha,\text{lex}(\beta,\alpha))$$ where $\text{lex}(\beta,\alpha)$ is the lexicographical ordering on $\beta \times \alpha$, is easily seen to be absolute by the methods of $\S3$.

Now, yes, from $\S3$ we know that $\beta \times \alpha$ is absolute, among many other results, but he shows in chapter $5$ that $\mathrm{type}(A,R)$ is absolute (assuming $\sf{ZF}-\sf{P}$), and furthermore that the statement "$R$ well-orders $A$" is absolute (again, assuming $\sf{ZF}-\sf{P}$); both of the latter results are shown in theorem $5.4$. Can one do without these results? If not, why is he not explicitly referring to them?

You have a slight transcription error. The way it's written in the book:

where $\text{lex}(\beta,\alpha)$, the lexicographical ordering on $\beta \times \alpha$, is easily seen to be absolute by the methods of $\S3$.

makes it clear that he only intends to say $\operatorname{lex}(\beta,\alpha)$ is absolute "by the methods of section 3" (i.e. show it yourself... section 3 taught you how to do that). The absoluteness of the other functions used in the expression ($\operatorname{type}(A,R)$ and $\beta\times \alpha$) have already appeared explicitly as theorems, as you note. He's just leaving it up to the reader to know that.

Thanks (again) @spaceisdarkgreen for clearing up my confusion =). I can't tag you in my replies, I think, but perhaps that is intentional?
